# Detect applications with same sharedUserId

Tags: android, android-manifest, ipc

Is there a way to get applications having same `shareUserId` from a third application. I mean i wish to detect the 2 applications having same `sharedUserId` from my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `PackageManager` and check user Id of each of installed package. There is `sharedUserId` field in [PackageInfo structure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) which will be set if package uses it.

Comment: Thanks... Will check it later and come back to you if that does not help

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to just improve the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13142107/4744263) from @Marcin Orlowski here.

The way to get the `sharedUserId` in Kotlin is:

```
context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0).sharedUserId
```

But it only works if you have defined the `sharedUserId` on the app's Manifest file, otherwise you'll get a null return when calling the above code.

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:sharedUserId="your-sharedUserId"
```